# How to convert string to a dict type in python

Tags: python

I have a string that I would like to convert to dict type in python.

Sample string :

```
'projectid=871106/interactionmonth=201701'
```

Expected output:

```
{"projectid":871106,"interactionmonth":201701}
```

Comment: Please make an attempt before asking. SO is neither a tutorial nor a free coding site. We deal with issues in code you've written.

Comment: I've been trying the full  morning, the only solution  I can think of is using replace and substring. I would like to know if there is a better approach.

Comment: Show what you have, explain why it doesn't work to your satisfaction. Do it by editing the question itself.

Comment: `dict(zip(("projectid", "interactionmonth"), map(int, re.fullmatch(r"projectid=(\d+)/interactionmonth=(\d{6})", 'projectid=871106/interactionmonth=201701').groups())))`

Comment: Also `dict((k, int(v)) for i in s.split('/') for k, _, v in (i.partition('='),))` (where `s = 'projectid=871106/interactionmonth=201701'`).

Answer (score 0):

```
input = 'projectid=871106/interactionmonth=201701'

key = ""
value = ""
switch = False
result = {}
for character in range(len(input)):
    if input[character] == "=": switch = True
    elif input[character] == "/" or character == len(input) - 1:
        result[key] = int(value)
        switch = False
        key = ""
        value = ""
    else:
        if (switch): value += input[character]
        else : key += input[character]
print(result)
```

OUPUT:

```
{'projectid': 871106, 'interactionmonth': 20170}
```

Comment: Why would you name an _index_ variable `character` instead of say `i`? There are other two ways of iterating over `input`: `for character in input` and `for i, character in enumerate(input)` if you want both the index and the character.